# Find digits in the sublists of the list and sum it

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a deeply nested list of such formats.

```
[['A',
  1668034967,
  [[322211651,
    'foo1',
    'foo2',
    'foo3',
    '1528'] # this 'row',
   [241737340,
    'foo1',
    'foo2',
    'foo3',
    '1032']]] # this 'row',
['B',
  1668034968,
  [[173817552,
    'foo1',
    'foo2',
    'foo3',
    '2196']]]]  # this 'row'
```

I need to sum up all the selected values in the sublists (See comments).
Therefore, the output would be:
`1528 + 1032 + 2196 = 4756`

I thought about lambdas and list comprehensions but that list is very deep, so I do not know how to utilize lambdas correctly.

I tried such

```
tests = # the list before in example
[int(x[2][0][4]) for x in tests]
# results in [1528, 2196] however I need [1528, 1032, 2196]
```

Comment: what is the determining factor in selecting which numbers are to be summed? The fact that they are at depth > 3, or the fact that they are given as strings, or something else?

Comment: I tried `[int(x[2][0][4]) for x in testst]`, however it does not include `1032` from the `A` list.

Comment: but again, what is the criterion?  I mean, there are lots of numbers in the flatten list, for example.

Comment: That they are at depth > 3 with a location of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you can select the right part in your nested lists:

```py
>>> [v[-1] for sub in mylist for v in sub[-1]]
['1528', '1032', '2196']
```

Then, sum them, as `int`:

```py
>>> sum([int(v[-1]) for sub in mylist for v in sub[-1]])
4756
```